# JS Focus Scrollable Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that opens up a scrollable div.

If i use the arrow keys on the keyboard, it wont scroll the div.

However, if i click on the div (anywhere) i can scroll using arrow keys.

How can i make the div automatically focused ? I have tryed using raw `.focus()`, ive tryed using jquery as well: `$(elm).focus()` and `$(elm).click()` both wont work. Any ideas how to achieve this ?

The element selector is correct, im selecting the div that contains the scrollbar.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet with what you are working with?

Comment: Its not gonna be very helpfull thats why i didnt.

After the dialog opens: 
```
  var focusElement = document.querySelector('#DocumentPage');
         console.log(focusElement); // prints the scrollable div correctly
         $(focusElement).focus();
```

Comment: Try with $( "#DocumentPage" ).trigger( "click" );. I'm not sure, but it worth a try.

Comment: did not work :( It seems only work if i click manually.

Answer (score 1):

In order to focus a element, you need a TabIndex. Adding a tabIndex then calling `.focus()` solves the problem.